# How to get the first result of a left join with Doctrine and postgreSQL

Tags: php, postgresql, doctrine-orm

In a project using Doctrine 2 and a postgreSQL database, I have a simple one to many relationship between the entity Gynecologist and his emails and telephone numbers. I would like to query the database to get one row for each person with the first inserted email and number.
I expect a result like the following:

```
-------------------
SURNAME  | NAME  | EMAIL           | TEL. NR.|
Surname1 | Name1 | email1@gmail.it | number1 |
-------------------
```

I tried:

```
$columns = array('g.id', 'g.companyName', 'g.surname', 'g.name', 'e.email', 't.number');

$queryBuilder = $this->getDoctrine()
    ->getRepository('AppBundle:Gynecologist')
    ->createQueryBuilder('g')
    ->select($columns)
    ->join('g.emails', 'e')
    ->join('g.telephoneNumbers', 't')
    ->orderBy('g.surname', 'ASC')
    ->addOrderBy('g.name', 'ASC')
    ->groupBy('g.id')
    ->addGroupBy('g.companyName')
    ->addGroupBy('g.surname')
    ->addGroupBy('g.name')
    ->addGroupBy('e.email')
    ->addGroupBy('t.number');
```

This is the generated query:

```
SELECT g0_.id AS id_0, g0_.company_name AS company_name_1, g0_.surname AS surname_2, g0_.name AS name_3, g1_.email AS email_4, g2_.number AS number_5 
FROM gynecologists 
g0_ INNER JOIN gynecologists_emails g1_ ON g0_.id = g1_.gynecologist_id 
INNER JOIN gynecologists_telephone_numbers g2_ ON g0_.id = g2_.gynecologist_id
GROUP BY g0_.id, g0_.company_name, g0_.surname, g0_.name, g1_.email, g2_.number 
ORDER BY g0_.surname ASC, g0_.name ASC 
LIMIT 500 OFFSET 0
```

According to a suggestion received by a StackOverflow user, I tried also:

```
$columns = array('DISTINCT g.id', 'g.companyName', 'g.surname', 'g.name', 'e.email', 't.number');

$queryBuilder = $this->getDoctrine()
    ->getRepository('AppBundle:Gynecologist')
    ->createQueryBuilder('g')
    ->select($columns)
    ->join('g.emails', 'e')
    ->join('g.telephoneNumbers', 't')
    ->orderBy('g.surname', 'ASC')
    ->addOrderBy('g.name', 'ASC');

SELECT DISTINCT g0_.id AS id_0, g0_.company_name AS company_name_1, g0_.surname AS surname_2, g0_.name AS name_3, g1_.email AS email_4, g2_.number AS number_5 
FROM gynecologists g0_ 
INNER JOIN gynecologists_emails g1_ ON g0_.id = g1_.gynecologist_id 
INNER JOIN gynecologists_telephone_numbers g2_ ON g0_.id = g2_.gynecologist_id
ORDER BY g0_.surname ASC, g0_.name ASC 
LIMIT 500 OFFSET 0
```

But the result is always:

```
-------------------
SURNAME  | NAME  | EMAIL           | TEL. NR.|
Surname1 | Name1 | email1@gmail.it | number1 |
Surname1 | Name1 | email1@gmail.it | number2 |
Surname1 | Name1 | email2@gmail.it | number1 |
Surname1 | Name1 | emai21@gmail.it | number2 |
-------------------
```

Thank you.

Comment: When using group by, all columns selected must be either in the group by columns, or used with an aggregate function, like max(), avg()...

Comment: Ok. But how to fix the query to return just one row per person? Grouping by the selected column I got as many rows per person as the number of emails or telephone numbers saved...

Comment: Could you add generated query?

Comment: Done, I edited the post.

Comment: How do you determine  first inserted email and number? is there any rule?

Comment: I would like emails and numbers with the smallest id. Should I add another order by rule?

Answer (score 0):

I think it should work for you:

```
$columns = array('DISTINCT g.id', 'g.companyName', 'g.surname', 'g.name', 'e.email', 't.number');

$queryBuilder = $this->getDoctrine()
    ->getRepository('AppBundle:Gynecologist')
    ->createQueryBuilder('g')
    ->select($columns)
    ->join('g.emails', 'e')
    ->join('g.telephoneNumbers', 't')
    ->orderBy('g.surname', 'ASC')
    ->addOrderBy('g.name', 'ASC');
```

Comment: It doesn't work. I edited my message according to your suggestion. Thank you